# How can I reinstall mysql/mysqld on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, mysql

I'm experiencing some issues where the `mysqld` won't start, so I'd like to purge or (at least) reinstall its files in order to replace the current configuration files with the stock ones so that it will start again.

This is the content of `journalctl -xeu mysqld.service`:

```
░░ The job identifier is 276.
sep. 30 08:03:48 oberkommando systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysqld.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
sep. 30 08:03:48 oberkommando systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ The unit mysqld.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
sep. 30 08:03:48 oberkommando systemd[1]: Failed to start mysqld.service - MySQL Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysqld.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mysqld.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 276 and the job result is failed.
```

This is the content of `/var/log/mysqld.log`:

```
2022-09-28T22:24:53.958318Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2022-09-28T22:24:53.958374Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
2022-09-28T22:24:53.958389Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
2022-09-28T22:24:53.958410Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012215] [InnoDB] Cannot open datafile './ibdata1'
2022-09-28T22:24:53.958444Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012959] [InnoDB] Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2022-09-28T22:24:53.958457Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file.
2022-09-28T22:24:54.458706Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-28T22:24:54.458838Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-28T22:24:54.458861Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-28T22:24:54.459186Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-09-29T09:52:22.805182Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1440
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-09-29T09:52:22.817204Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-29T09:52:22.817266Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-09-29T10:09:29.182680Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1455
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-09-29T10:09:29.186705Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-29T10:09:29.186770Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-09-29T10:14:02.494574Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 5767
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-09-29T10:14:02.495732Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-29T10:14:02.495795Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-09-29T19:49:57.027740Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1439
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-09-29T19:49:57.040203Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-29T19:49:57.040260Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-09-29T19:51:25.624747Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-09-29T19:51:25.624780Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 2639
2022-09-29T19:51:25.626154Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-09-29T19:51:25.626157Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-09-29T19:51:25.626617Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-29T19:51:25.626673Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-09-30T06:03:48.888324Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-09-30T06:03:48.888374Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1454
2022-09-30T06:03:48.900171Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-09-30T06:03:48.900174Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-09-30T06:03:48.901992Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-30T06:03:48.902046Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I'm using Fedora 36 and have installed the following packages

```
mysql80-community-release-fc36-1.noarch
mysql-community-common-8.0.30-10.fc36.x86_64
mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.30-10.fc36.x86_64
mysql-community-libs-8.0.30-10.fc36.x86_64
mysql-community-client-8.0.30-10.fc36.x86_64
mysql-community-icu-data-files-8.0.30-10.fc36.x86_64
mysql-community-server-8.0.30-10.fc36.x86_64
mysql-workbench-community-8.0.30-1.fc36.x86_64
```

using [MySQL's website](https://i.ibb.co/2PNyZ2T/screencap.png).

The thing is that I wanted to uninstall it, but it wants to remove too many dependencies, and Fedora doesn't allow leaving dependencies installed if it means they are broken.

Comment: do you also want to delete all data inside the database or do you want to keep the data?

Comment: @toppk in this case, I don't mind nuking the whole thing. How would one go about it if I'd like to keep my data?

Comment: It looks like a permissioning issue of the  /var/lib/mysql directory.  I would examine the systemd unit, the directory and /etc/passwd for mysql account to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
sudo systemctl stop mysqld # not sure it's called this way
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql # this will wipe out all the data inside the database - @toppk
sudo dnf reinstall mysql-community-server
```

Comment: this will wipe out all the data inside the database, which is not clear from OP that is what they want.

Comment: Added your comment. Considering the question the OP has troubles with missing files and permissions, I thought they are not needed.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov worked a charm. Thanks. Yes, `sudo systemctl stop mysqld` is the right command :)